# HttpClient and WebClient requests / responses don't work for intranet with DefaultCredentials

Tags: .net-core, httpclient, webclient, intranet

Problem: I am unable to get content from an company internal webpage through using HttpClient or WebClient. I am able to get the content by accessing the URL directly, however.

Details: .NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages, IIS 10, Windows Authentication.

I have a website http://myintranet/Editor/Bib/4343 where a user can press a button to generate a static page. Behind the scenes, it attempts to read a stream from http://myintranet/Editor/NewBib/4343/true and create a static HTML page from it.

When clicking the button, the response is always `IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 401.1 - Unauthorized` etc.

However when I access the webpage directly in the browser, it opens up just fine (note that if it is the first time accessing the website, I am prompted by the browser to enter my username and password. After that, the browser remembers these credentials).

Also note that when running it from localhost through Visual Studio, all works fine, the static page downloads properly too.

Here is my code:

Version 1:

```
public IActionResult OnPostGenerateStaticPage()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true, PreAuthenticate = true });
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(Url.PageLink().Replace("Bib", "NewBib") + "/true").Result;
                var indexPageContents = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

                var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                {
                    FileName = BibNumber + ".htm",
                    Inline = false,
                };
                Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
                return File(indexPageContents, "text/html");
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./Bib");
            }
        }
```

Version 2:

```
public IActionResult OnPostGenerateStaticPage()
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true };       
                string desiredUrl = Url.PageLink().Replace("Bib", "NewBib") + "/true";
                var indexPageContents = client.OpenRead("desiredUrl");

                var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                {
                    FileName = BibNumber + ".htm",
                    Inline = false,
                };
                Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
                return File(indexPageContents, "text/html");
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./Bib");
            }
        }
```

Another thing, I have asked the web server admin to check that NTLM is above Negotiate for the authentication providers for this website and it is. Also, Anonymous and Basic Authentication are disabled and Windows Authentication is enabled.

Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: I think you see this because your server code is asking to be authenticated by the currently logged in user which would be whatever account your site is hosted under. When you run from VS, you're running that code as you, so you are authenticated.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I gave this a shot, but it also doesn't work: 
`HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = false, Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("me", "mypwd", "MYDOMAIN") });`
This also doesn't work. 
What else can I try?